# Decryption data in Android with RSA, How to decode the original string

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I am using the following class to encrypt and decrypt the RSA algorithm, but it does not return the original information to me at the time of decryption.

```
    public static byte[] decryptByPrivateKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);


        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }


      public static byte[] encryptByPublicKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
          KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);



    }
```

My algorithm output

```
g� ��K�i���K�?��?����r��Sm1�(�qZ��PiJf�.�����a��/�a�VВ6�;�0�7��.�e˿�����P�ȇi��H�Y��v��eHh\,�U%C[ʊ  �
```

And when I use the following line, I will not have any output at all and shows me the following error

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

error:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:04000084:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:PKCS_DECODING_ERROR
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the byte[] from "decryptByPrivateKey" method to base64?.  Try new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded));

Comment: On encryption side - what is the value of "keyFactory.getAlgorithm()" ? Did you debug the values of "KEY_ALGORITHM" ?

Comment: @SonuSanjeev Thank you for posting
In this case I need my data as a byte array so I do not convert my data to 64 base format

Comment: @MichaelFehr 
Thanks for posting
Yes, I have fixed the value of "KEY_ALGORITHM" and it gives me the correct output. I have no problem with this.

Comment: Please post the missing methods and variables: `decryptBASE64()` and `KEY_ALGORITHM`. The problem could be caused by the private and public keys not belonging together, or by a different padding. When encrypting and decrypting, instantiate the cipher with a _consistent_ padding, e.g. `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")`. If the problem still occurs, check the keys.

Comment: @user9014097
Thank you very much for your time, you are right
Your guidance helped me
But I found another problem, that when I change the pair of private and public keys, encryption takes place, but decryption does not take place.
With new public and private keys

Comment: You should edit your question and post the _full_ code you are currently using and _test_ data with which the problem is reproducible (plaintext, ciphertext and key pair). Binary data, such as the ciphertext, can be Base64 encoded.